# Pioneer DVD-ROM will not eject after some time of system usage

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, cd-burning, dvd-burning

I'm having an odd issue where after my Mac Pro works for a certain amount of time (it seems variable), the drive will no longer seemingly be recognized.  It shows up in the hardware profile for the system, however when I hit the eject key, Toast starts up instead of my drive responding.  Further, when Toast or any other CD / DVD writing utility is started, the drive is not recognized in these applications.  Any idea as to what could potentially be going on here?

The thing that throws me the real curve ball is that it DOES work for a little while when the system is restarted and then just "disappears" as noted.

NOTE: Even when Toast is not in the mix Disk Utility and other apps will not recognize the drive.  It is obviously some kind of an OS issue in terms of it still showing up in the hardware profile, yet no applications are able to detect / use it properly.

Comment: I know what a Toast is? but has nothing to do with computers. so please specify, including what version you have. an example would be ....Roxyo Toast titanium v 11

Comment: @Buscar웃 it has nothing to do with Toast actually.  The point is that the Mac Pro simply stops seeing the optical drive and then fires up an application that is normally associated with the device when using the eject key on the keyboard.  So this is an OS issue of some type.

Comment: to quote you: it still shows in hardware profile, when you use the eject the Toast starts ? how can that not be the Toast software problem?

Comment: Because when Toast is deleted the same thing happens.  Nothing at all will occur.  Mac OS X cannot recognize the drive in Disk Utility even when it shows up under the hardware profile.

Comment: if it shows in hardware profile then it is recognized. I believe the Toast.app has modified your keyboard and keyboard shortcuts. Which Eject do you use?

Comment: No, it has not modified the keyboard shortcuts.  `drutil eject ` and `drutil eject internal` do not eject it either.  `drutil list` does not show any device, yet the following is seen in System Information: http://cl.ly/image/2r2w1k3N0L36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that OS X presently does not know how to properly wake all optical drive devices.  Turning off "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" has seemingly resolved it for the time being and this has been reported to Apple.

[image]